# Imperative vs conditional "must"

Tags: word-difference

"Li diris ke mi estu kvieta" implies that he said that I ought to be be quiet (a suggestion/desire/implicit command).
"Li diris ke mi devas esti kvieta" means that he said that I *must* be quiet (a mandate).
What would "Li diris ke mi devus esti kvieta" mean/imply, in comparison to the previous two? That I should be quiet, but not necessarily in the sense of an implied command or desire?

**Current understanding**

- "Li diris ke mi estu kvieta" - A suggestion or desire that I should be quiet.

  - e.g. "Mi ludis violonon kiam li estis studanta, tial li diris ke mi estu kvieta."
  - Actually, now that I look at it, I think "diris" is incorrect here, as the following "esti" would not be subjunctive. I suppose it could be "volis" instead.
- "Li diris ke mi devas esti kvieta" - An obligatory action imposed upon me.

  - e.g. "Ni estis promenanta tra la tombejo, tial li diris ke mi devas esti kvieta."
- "Li diris ke mi devus esti kvieta" - A statement implying that I am currently not quiet, but should be.

  - e.g. "Ni estis kaŝiĝanta ĉirkaŭe la sekreta bazo, tial li diris ke mi devus esti kvieta."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the difference between *devas* and *u-modo* to be that of external and internal obligation (cf. *ändern/verändern* in German or *ändra/förändra* in Swedish). Mona the Monad already stated:

> *Li diris, ke mi devas esti kvieta* : an obligatory action imposed upon me
>
> *Li diris, ke mi estu kvieta* : a suggestion or desire that I should be quiet; it is in my  own interest to be quiet

In contrast the *us-modo* or *imaga modo* in Esperanto is used to express a condition:

- *Kvankam mi venkus en la loterio, mi ne lasus mian laboron.*

[PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/imaga.html) stresses, that the action must be imaginary, i.e. the winning in the sentence above is only imagined. *Imaga modo* should not be used, if the situation can be real.

- *Se li est**us** ĉi tie, li certe mir**us** pri la malordo* : It is known, that he isn't here, but if one would imagine him to be here, he would be amazed.
- *Se li est**as** ĉi tie, li certe mir**as** pri la malordo* : It is not known, whether he is here or not, but if he is, he would/will be amazed.

Note, that other languages may use, what they call conditional mood, in both cases. This one of the reasons PMEG avoids using traditional terminology and speaks about different modes (*reala modo, imaga modo* etc.).

The verb forms *devus, povus* and *volus* sometimes express a real obligation or request to do something, but the imaginary aspect reveals, that the action of the other verb is currently not in progress (for further info see [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/gravaj_verboj/povi_devi_voli/us.html)).

- *Mi devus labori* : there is an obligation for me to work, but I'm not currently working
- *Mi povus foriri* : I could leave, but I stay at least for now
- *Mi volus helpi al vi* : I do want to help you, but for some reason I don't – at least right now

The *us-modo* doesn't express time, i.e. it can also be used for past events. Therefore

- *Li diris, ke mi devus esti kvieta* : He said, that I should have been quiet (but I wasn't).

Having said that it's better to the simple *-is* tense, if the context clearly shows, that the action could have happened, but didn't actually happen.

- *Mi volis lin bati, sed li forkuris de mi* : I would have wanted to hit him, but he ran away.

Comment: Vi pravas. Mi reskribis mian respondon.

Comment: Ĝi estas multe pli utila nun. Dankon!

Answer (score 1):

```
Li diris, ke mi devas esti kvieta por vidi la sciurojn en la arboj.
Li diris, ke mi devas esti kvieta por ke ni vidu la sciurojn en la arboj.
Li diris, ke mi estu kvieta por vidi la sciurojn en la arboj.
Li diris, ke mi estu kvieta por ke ni vidu la sciurojn en la arboj.
```

The first two sentences just tell the condition for seeing squirrels in the trees.
The last two sentences wants me to be quiet in order to see the squirrels.

```
Li diris, ke mi devus esti kvieta por vidi la sciurojn en la arboj.
Li diris, ke mi devus esti kvieta por ke ni vidu la sciurojn en la arboj.
```

I should be quiet in order to see the squirrels. *No implied command, conditional mode on a condition. Assuming no realisation.*

The `estu kvieta` is the normal conversational tone.

Answer (score 0):

La grava diferenco inter

> Li diris ke mi estu kvieta.

kaj

> Li diris ke mi devus esti kvieta.

estas, ke per la unua frazo estas indikata, ke *li* kaj la dezirinta estas la sama. En la dua frazo ne estas esprimata kiu deziris. Eble neniu deziris, sed la devo havas alian kaŭzon. Krome, la unua frazo montras, ke dezirado estis esprimata per **diri** *estu kvieta*, dum la dua frazo montras nenion pri la estiĝo de la devo.

En la PMEG estas skribita pri [verboformoj en *ke*-frazoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/verboformoj.html#i-b8u):

> Por vidi, kian verboformon oni uzu en *ke*-frazo, oni povas provi memstarigi la *ke*-frazon. Oni disigu ĝin de ĝia ĉeffrazo kreante du memstarajn frazojn. Se tia disigo estas facile farebla, oni simple elektu por la *ke*-frazo la saman verboformon, kiun ĝi havus, se ĝi aperus memstare.

Do la ekzemplaj frazoj, kiuj enhavas nerektan parolon, fariĝas:

> Li diris ke mi estu kvieta. → Li diris: “Estu kvieta.”/“X estu kvieta.”
>
> Li diris ke mi devus esti kvieta. → Li diris: “X devus esti kvieta.”

En la PMEG oni ankaŭ legas pri [nerekta parolo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/nerekta_parolo/verboformoj.html):

> En iuj lingvoj oni devas ĉe nerekta parolo iafoje ŝanĝi la verboformon. En Esperanto oni ĉiam konservas la originan verboformon.

Tie ĉi jena ekzemplo troviĝas:

> Ili ordonis: “Paku tuj vian valizon!” → Ili ordonis, ke mi tuj paku mian valizon.

Laŭ tiuj klarigoj sendube, en la unua frazo (*Li diris ke mi estu kvieta.*), la subjekto de la ĉeffrazo kaj la esprimanto de la deziro estas la sama persono kaj la frazo montras la manieron de la dezirado. Kaŭzo por tio estas la *u*-verboformo en nerekta parolo.

Oni povas provi ĉi tiujn asertojn per anstataŭigi la verbon *diris* per tia verbo, kiu sekvigas ne nerektan parolon aŭ ne ordonon. Oni antaŭvidas, ke tiam la unua ekzempla frazo iĝas nevalida. Komparu:

> Li supozis/dubis/ekkonis/aprobis ke mi estu kvieta.
>
> Li supozis/dubis/ekkonis/aprobis ke mi devus esti kvieta.